# Why is my XIB view displayed as a square?

Tags: xcode, xib

My XIB is displayed as a square in Xcode and I don't know how to change it to the "phone" shape.

When I create the view everything is fine, it's when I switch to another view or swift file and then comeback that it's messed up. A work arround is to click on the "Version Editor" then back to the standard editor and it finally show up properly.

[image]

Comment: select view -> go to attribute inspector -> change size from freedom to inferred Or vice versa according yo your need.

Comment: I just tried that, even though I drag the edge of the square nothing change it remains the same

Comment: then we need to see it in Xcode can't tell anything more than this ...

Comment: When I create the view everything is fine, it's when I switch to another view or swift file and then comeback that it's messed up. A work arround is to click on the "Version Editor" then back to the standard editor and it finally show up properly. But it's really strange, I wonder if it can be an Xcode bug

Comment: i am thinking this too Xcode version ?

Comment: also add this description to your question it will help people to understand your question more clearly

Comment: Latest, 10.2.1 none of my colleagues seem to have the problem maybe this is from my installation

Comment: in that case you may be in need to update xibs interface builder document "open in " latest Xcode